# How to write code for replacing result in integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have about 100 integral term, the general form of them is as follows:

> $$\int \int dx~dy~N_\mu(x)~N_\nu(x)~F(x,y)~A_\nu(y)$$

For each $\mu$ and $\nu$, the definition of functions are different.
I have a definite answer for each $\mu$ and $\nu$ for $\int dx~N_\mu(x)~N_\nu(x)~F(x,y)$, (for instance $\int dx~N_1(x)~N_\nu(x)~F(x,y)=term10[1, 0]$)
and I've put them all on the list.

```
term10[1, 0] := 25*pi*(1. + 543*y + 12^y^3)
term11[1, 1] := -208*(3*y + 3)


termList = 
 List[term10[1, 0], term11[1, 1], term12[1, 2], term13[1, 3], 
 term14[1, 4], term15[1, 5], term16[1, 6], term17[1, 7], 
 term18[1, 8], term19[1, 9], term20[2, 0], term21[2, 1], 
 term22[2, 2], term23[2, 3], term24[2, 4], term25[2, 5], 
 term26[2, 6], term27[2, 7], term28[2, 8], term29[2, 9], 
 term30[3, 0], term31[3, 1], term32[3, 2], term33[3, 3], 
 term34[3, 4], term35[3, 5], term36[3, 6], term37[3, 7], 
 term38[3, 8], term39[3, 9], term40[4, 0], term41[4, 1], 
 term42[4, 2], term43[4, 3], term44[4, 4], term45[4, 5], 
 term46[4, 6], term47[4, 7], term48[4, 8], term49[4, 9], 
 term50[5, 0], term51[5, 1], term52[5, 2], term53[5, 3], 
 term54[5, 4], term55[5, 5], term56[5, 6], term57[5, 7], 
 term58[5, 8], term59[5, 9], term60[6, 0], term61[6, 1], 
 term62[6, 2], term63[6, 3], term64[6, 4], term65[6, 5], 
 term66[6, 6], term67[6, 7], term68[6, 8], term69[6, 9], 
 term70[7, 0], term71[7, 1], term72[7, 2], term73[7, 3], 
 term74[7, 4], term75[7, 5], term76[7, 6], term77[7, 7], 
 term78[7, 8], term10[7, 9], term80[8, 0], term81[8, 1], 
 term82[8, 2], term83[8, 3], term84[8, 4], term85[8, 5], 
 term86[8, 6], term87[8, 7], term10[8, 8], term89[8, 9], 
 term90[9, 0], term91[9, 1], term92[9, 2], term93[9, 3], 
 term94[9, 4], term95[9, 5], term96[9, 6], term10[9, 7], 
 term98[9, 8], term10[9, 9]]

   bet*gGgG*meta^2*
Integrate[N[0]*N[0]*F[x, y]*A[0, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(188*Pi^2) + 
bet*gGgG^3*meta^2*Integrate[N[0]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[0, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
1}]/(75*Pi^4) + 
bet^2*gGgG*meta^2*
Integrate[N[0]*N[2]*F[x, y]*A[0, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(1843*Pi^4) + 
jet*meta^2*
Integrate[N[0]*N[3]*F[x, y]*A[0, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(564*Pi^3)
 cc*gGgG^5*meta^2*
 Integrate[N[1]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(75*Pi^4) + 
 fpar*gGgG*meta^2*
 Integrate[N[1]*N[2]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(564*Pi^3) + 
 mcc*gGgG*meta^2*
 Integrate[N[1]*N[3]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(788*Pi^4) + 
 mcc*gGgG^3*meta^2*
 Integrate[N[2]*N[2]*F[x, y]*A[2, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(75*Pi^4)+
 dd*gGgG*meta^2*
 Integrate[N[2]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[2, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]/(564*Pi^3) +...
```

So I need a code to replace  results `term mu nu[mu, nu]` into integrals, for calculating the next integral.
maybe `TransformationFunctions` can help, but I don't know how use it.

Comment: `term[mu_Integer, nu_Integer[ := Integrate[<integrand code>, x, y]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `term[mu_Integer, nu_Integer] :=...`

Comment: @rhermans Thanks.  Might also be that the integration should be `Integrate[term10[mu, nu] A[nu, y], y]`.  After helping thousands of folks on this site, with descriptions of code of varying clarity and accuracy, I feel there's no better substitute for complete working code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 as I said I have 100 term, I should replace each integral with  $term\mu\nu[\mu, \nu]$ for 100 term. My problem is that I don't wanted replace $term\mu\nu[\mu, \nu]$ with $\int dx~N_\mu(x)~N_\nu(x)~F(x,y)$, manually

Comment: @rhermans I think I have not explained well `Integrate[N[1]*N[2]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] +Integrate[N[0]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[0, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 3}] +Integrate[N[1]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]+Integrate[N[1]*N[3]*F[x, y]*A[1, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] + Integrate[N[3]*N[1]*F[x, y]*A[3, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] + ...`. I mean, I need a code that replace for example N[1]*N[1]*F[x, y] with result that is presented in list (in this case `term11[1,1]`).

Comment: That's why I wrote a general rule to replace all of them with one line of code.  Now, you have 'term10[0, 0]` in your question, but your comment suggests that it should have been `term00[0, 0]`.  Is that so?  If yes, then I was mislead.  If you gave them all different names $term\mu\nu$, then that will prove somewhat inconvenient.  As I said, complete code is the best way to get good help with problems.  A minimal working example (MWE) is what the community generally prefers, esp. if you code is very long.

Comment: @ Michael E2 I edited my question maybe it can help.thank you so much.